# Change capacitance or resistance in RC circuit

Tags: filter, passive-networks

When tuning an RC circuit you can choose either to tweak the resistance or the capacitance.  I was wondering if there are any benefits for choosing one over the other depending on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: How about price and availability  of the components (either at the shop or in your drawer cabinet at home)? And of course the resulting in- and output impedance. Do you have a specific RC circuit in mind? Please upload a circuit diagram.

Comment: Do you need to tune the circuit when in use, or just during the design process?  Since the former requires an variable resistor or capacitor (see Barry's answer below), but the latter can be done with a resistance and/or capacitance box, the values measured, and then fixed components used in the final circuit.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to give a definitive answer to your question because it is too general.  However some general comments can be made.  Unless your frequency range is such that the capacitor is small (i.e. measured in picofarads), it is probably better to use a variable resistor since they are available over a very wide range of values (from ohms to megohms).  Variable capacitors above around 1000 pf are not easily available and can get physically large.  Since RC circuits do not have sharp frequency response characteristics, it is probably better to "tune" your circuit by selecting values rather than by using variable components.  Fixed components have better accuracy, more stability with both time and temperature, and are cheaper.  If you do need to do precise tuning, variable resistors are probably still a better choice since they are readily available as multi-turn components.  Most variable capacitors are less than one turn.  If you can provide more information as to your application, than I and others can provide more guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend use of a fixed capacitor and if needed a variable resistor.

In addition to what Barry wrote, variable capacitors are also very sensitive to surrounding objects making them hard to tune. Usually a special tuning tool is needed to operate the capacitor correctly, since using a metal screwdriver will change the capacitance of the capacitor. Tuning tools are designed to make the impact as small as possible, but sometimes it will happen that you tune the capacitor to just the right frequency and as soon as you remove the tool from it, it will change.

Another point is important when using "high capacitance" (as in higher than picofarad range) capacitors. Smaller capacitors are usually much easier to find using [Class 1 dielectrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EIA_Class_1_dielectric) while larger capacitors usually use [Class 2 dielectrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X7R) which means that they have much greater tolerances.

On the other hand, resistors with tight tolerances are much more common and cheaper, so in general it is easier to get a capacitor and then closely match a resistor to it than to get a resistor and match a capacitor to it.

Also as Barry said, multiturn variable resistors are much more common and can be used to precisely set the required resistance. Unlike variable capacitors, they do not require special tuning tools and won't change their value based on the distance of your hand to them. Their downside is that some types are inductive, so read the datasheet first and see if that will be a problem for you.